# HardCacheWeakIdentityMap can't acquire read lock

Tags: java, multithreading, osgi, eclipselink

We have an OSGi (Java) application, where we use eclipseLink to interact with a mssql database.

Once in a while the system gets in a sort of deadlock. When I pause and check all threads, I see that one thread is causing a problem.

```
Name: pool-40-thread-1
State: WAITING on org.eclipse.persistence.internal.identitymaps.HardCacheWeakIdentityMap$ReferenceCacheKey@24c6f90c
Total blocked: 2  Total waited: 22

Stack trace: 
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ConcurrencyManager.acquireReadLock(ConcurrencyManager.java:236)
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.identitymaps.CacheKey.acquireReadLock(CacheKey.java:277)
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ConcurrencyManager.checkReadLock(ConcurrencyManager.java:224)
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.identitymaps.CacheKey.checkReadLock(CacheKey.java:255)
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.identitymaps.IdentityMapManager.getFromIdentityMap(IdentityMapManager.java:805)
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.IdentityMapAccessor.getFromLocalIdentityMap(IdentityMapAccessor.java:437)
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.checkCacheForObject(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:857)
org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.checkEarlyReturnLocal(ReadObjectQuery.java:246)
org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.checkEarlyReturn(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:846)
org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.checkEarlyReturn(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:872)
org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:836)
org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1127)
org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.execute(ReadObjectQuery.java:431)
org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1215)
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1786)
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1737)
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.executeQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:900)
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.findInternal(EntityManagerImpl.java:843)
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:719)
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:588)
org.amdatu.jpa.extender.DelegatingEntityManager.find(DelegatingEntityManager.java:165)
   - locked org.amdatu.jpa.extender.DelegatingEntityManager@1e32127e
com.bekaert.handling.unit.spool.ws.location.ana.WsAnaLocationService.findUnitLocation(WsAnaLocationService.java:161)
com.bekaert.handling.unit.spool.ws.location.ana.WsAnaLocationService.findUnitLocation(WsAnaLocationService.java:1)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor16.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.amdatu.jta.manager.TransactionalAspect.invoke(TransactionalAspect.java:123)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.findUnitLocation(Unknown Source)
com.bekaert.handling.opc.trigger.ana.position.AnaPositionUpdateListener.updateUnits(AnaPositionUpdateListener.java:105)
com.bekaert.handling.opc.trigger.ana.position.AnaPositionUpdateListener.opcItemDataChanged(AnaPositionUpdateListener.java:68)
com.bekaert.opc.da.OpcDataChangeListeners$Listener$1.run(OpcDataChangeListeners.java:201)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

It seems that this thread is waiting for an acquireReadLock. But I can't find any other thread that has already a lock for this.

If I check the stack in eclipse, the

> waiting for: HardCacheWeakIdentityMap$ReferenceCacheKey (id=3019)

is not "owned by" anything.

Seems like this identityMap is waiting for nothing?
Or do I miss something here? Can I check something else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: EclipseLink uses its own locking mechanism, so try calling EclipseLink's printIdentityMapLocks() http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink/2.5.2/org/eclipse/persistence/internal/sessions/IdentityMapAccessor.java#IdentityMapAccessor.printIdentityMapLocks%28%29  to see which threads are holding the lock for the object being read.  You will likely find some other thread building objects, and this thread cannot return the object until the other thread is done building or merging into it.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the Session or the IdentityMapAccessor object. As I am using enittiyManager with JPA and Amdatu.
I still don't know what the root cause is, but adding     <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/> to my persistence.xml file helps.

Comment: That property prevents the use of a shared cache, which means Eclipselink doesn't need to use locking to maintain the cache.  If you are fine without the performance benefit of using a shared cache, then this is a valid solution.  You obtain the session from underneath the EntityManager  using JpaHelper.getEntityManager(em).getServerSession() or from a factory using JpaHelper.getServerSession(emf)